# Footnote Line Spacing: how to reduce?

Tags: footnotes, koma-script

I would like to shrink interline footnote spacing. Instead, the footnotes follow the leading spacing in the document. (edit: removed a few lines that "probably" do not create the problem.

MWE:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,paper=5.in:8.in,DIV=15,BCOR=12mm,headings=small, ]{scrbook} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{EB Garamond 12 Regular} % works

%% Footnotes
%\usepackage{bigfoot}
\frenchspacing
%\makeatletter
%\def\FN@baselinestretch{.8}
%\makeatother
\usepackage[flushmargin,multiple]{footmisc}

\usepackage{leading}
\leading{6.5mm}


\usepackage{setspace}   %%%% for epigraph

\sloppy
\linespread{.8}
%\scalefont{.85}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  Footnotes
\makeatletter
\def\FN@baselinestretch{.6}          %%%%%%%%%%  Not working
\makeatother

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sit     amet consequat nisi, ut interdum ipsum. Phasellus eu ex eu massa ornare    hendrerit vel vel eros. Donec ornare, mi sed lacinia pretium, lectus     ipsum venenatis lorem, in convallis lacus augue vitae nulla. Ut posuere   ac enim mattis scelerisque. Donec vitae ipsum vitae odio lobortis    varius. Aliquam rhoncus sagittis pellentesque. Curabitur erat nunc, dignissim id tincidunt vel, sodales ut nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Mauris ornare pharetra neque vel maximus. Donec in purus eu turpis luctus placerat. Vestibulum et rutrum nisi, ut sollicitudin lectus.

Donec ac \footnote{tristique nisi. Donec a porta elit. Morbi congue sapien sed eleifend facilisis. In cursus, diam eu tincidunt interdum, dui tellus luctus dolor, eu elementum nulla ligula non mi. Maecenas ac condimentum sapien. Donec volutpat odio neque, quis faucibus nibh congue ac. Donec scelerisque viverra nisl, at tristique velit gravida ut. Duis vel elit et tellus auctor elementum et quis augue. Nulla tincidunt, sapien et congue convallis, turpis metus lacinia nulla, et feugiat velit justo quis quam. Pellentesque egestas, nunc nec feugiat gravida, eros tellus finibus mi, sed interdum ex magna a elit. Cras nulla sem, pulvinar at dictum sodales, fringilla ut nisi.

Aenean placerat vulputate fermentum. Mauris laoreet rutrum mollis.  Nunc consequat, orci in condimentum efficitur, lectus urna condimentum risus, ut mollis ipsum nulla in diam. Nam viverra ipsum quis hendrerit feugiat. Morbi nec dictum urna. Quisque sapien tortor, dapibus id nulla eu, pulvinar faucibus ex. Curabitur nisi nunc, egestas et neque porttitor, gravida sollicitudin urna. Sed ut ex eros. Mauris quis condimentum dui. Maecenas ornare aliquam felis a venenatis. Nunc eget elit neque. Donec nec luctus sem.}

Phasellus eget tortor a felis volutpat imperdiet ut a tortor. Donec ut augue neque. Nullam tincidunt ipsum at lectus lobortis placerat. Etiam sagittis metus non tortor sagittis, quis tempor ipsum placerat. Duis et venenatis turpis. Donec a libero vitae ante dapibus accumsan. Integer porta tincidunt velit eu mollis. Sed id gravida risus. Vivamus non nisi nec risus condimentum tempor. Curabitur ultrices turpis ante, nec suscipit ligula accumsan a. Maecenas quis posuere elit. Aliquam erat volutpat.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Anyone? Bueller?

Comment: Removing the two \leading commands restores single space footnotes, but unfortunately the body text now has 1 1/2 spacing (approximately). What I'd like is for the body text to be set at .85 and the footnotes single spaced, as is seen in bible typography.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you need, but as you are using a KOMA-script class, I suggest to use its commands for footnotes. I deleted all code out of you example that can be replaced by KOMA-script commands.

For linespread I usually take the setspace package. The »multiple« option from footmisc is part of KOMA-script as well. For »flushmargin« the replacement might be the `\deffootnote` thing, but if not, provide more info what you need.

I used a Garamond font from my system, might be different on yours.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,paper=5.in:8.in,DIV=15,BCOR=12mm,headings=small,
footnotes=multiple]{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Garamond Libre}

\usepackage{setspace}   %%%% for epigraph

\deffootnote{1.5em}{1em}{%
  \makebox[1.5em][l]{\thefootnotemark}}
\setkomafont{footnote}{\fontsize{8.5pt}{8.5pt}\selectfont}


\begin{document}
\begin{spacing}{1.1}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sit amet consequat
  nisi, ut interdum ipsum. Phasellus eu ex eu massa ornare hendrerit vel vel
  eros. Donec ornare, mi sed lacinia pretium, lectus ipsum venenatis lorem, in
  convallis lacus augue vitae nulla. Ut posuere ac enim mattis scelerisque. Donec
  vitae ipsum vitae odio lobortis varius. Aliquam rhoncus sagittis
  pellentesque. Curabitur erat nunc, dignissim id tincidunt vel, sodales ut
  nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Mauris ornare pharetra neque vel maximus. Donec in
  purus eu turpis luctus placerat. Vestibulum et rutrum nisi, ut sollicitudin
  lectus.

  Donec ac \footnote{tristique nisi. Donec a porta elit. Morbi congue sapien sed
    eleifend facilisis. In cursus, diam eu tincidunt interdum, dui tellus luctus
    dolor, eu elementum nulla ligula non mi. Maecenas ac condimentum sapien. Donec
    volutpat odio neque, quis faucibus nibh congue ac. Donec scelerisque viverra
    nisl, at tristique velit gravida ut. Duis vel elit et tellus auctor elementum
    et quis augue. Nulla tincidunt, sapien et congue convallis, turpis metus
    lacinia nulla, et feugiat velit justo quis quam. Pellentesque egestas, nunc nec
    feugiat gravida, eros tellus finibus mi, sed interdum ex magna a elit. Cras
    nulla sem, pulvinar at dictum sodales, fringilla ut nisi.

    Aenean placerat vulputate fermentum. Mauris laoreet rutrum mollis.  Nunc
    consequat, orci in condimentum efficitur, lectus urna condimentum risus, ut
    mollis ipsum nulla in diam. Nam viverra ipsum quis hendrerit feugiat. Morbi nec
    dictum urna. Quisque sapien tortor, dapibus id nulla eu, pulvinar faucibus
    ex. Curabitur nisi nunc, egestas et neque porttitor, gravida sollicitudin
    urna. Sed ut ex eros. Mauris quis condimentum dui. Maecenas ornare aliquam
    felis a venenatis. Nunc eget elit neque. Donec nec luctus sem.} bla bla bla.

  Phasellus eget tortor a felis volutpat imperdiet ut a tortor. Donec ut augue
  neque. Nullam tincidunt ipsum at lectus lobortis placerat. Etiam sagittis metus
  non tortor sagittis, quis tempor ipsum placerat. Duis et venenatis turpis. Donec
  a libero vitae ante dapibus accumsan. Integer porta tincidunt velit eu
  mollis. Sed id gravida risus. Vivamus non nisi nec risus condimentum
  tempor. Curabitur ultrices turpis ante, nec suscipit ligula accumsan a. Maecenas
  quis posuere elit. Aliquam erat volutpat.
\end{spacing}

\end{document}
```

[image: pic of code]